# Check if custom prerequisite is installed using registry

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, registry, clickonce

I'm creating a CLickOnce installer for my application which relies on another application to work. I want the installer to install the other application, if it isn't already installed, before installing my own application.

To achieve this, I have created a custom prerequisite following [these (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee335701.aspx) instructions. As of now, the installer installs the other application and then my application, but it does not check if the other application is already installed.

Following examples from other prerequisites, I created an install check, in my prerequisite manifests, to check the value of a registry key that contains the application version. The issue is that the registry check always fails to read the registry. I have tried many other registry keys and it fails to read them. The ones that worked properly were:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SharedManagementObjects\CurrentVersion - Version

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer - Version
```

and other keys used by default Bootstrapper packages (DotNetFX40, SqlExpress2012, etc).

What is going on here? Why is the installer not able to read most registry keys?

---

My product.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Product
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper"
  ProductCode="TestAppSetup"
/>
```

and my package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper"  Name="Test" Culture="Culture">

    <!-- Defines list of files to be copied on build -->  
    <PackageFiles>
        <PackageFile Name="TestApp.exe"/>
    </PackageFiles>

    <InstallChecks>
        <RegistryCheck Property="TestVersion" Key="REGISTRY_KEY_HERE" Value="Version" />
    </InstallChecks>

    <Commands Reboot="Defer">
        <Command PackageFile="TestApp.exe" Arguments="">

            <!-- These checks determine whether the package is to be installed -->
            <InstallConditions>
                <!-- Bypasses if TestApp version 3.6.3 or above is already installed -->
                <BypassIf Property="TestApp" Compare="ValueGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="3.6.3"/>
                <!-- Block install if user does not have admin privileges -->
                <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>
                <!-- Block install on less than Windows XP SP2 -->
                <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="5.1.2" String="InvalidPlatformWinNT"/>
                <!-- Block install on W2K3 with no service pack -->
                <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionEqualTo" Value="5.2.0" String="InvalidPlatformWinNT"/>
                <!-- Block install if the platform is IA-64 -->
                <FailIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="IA64" String="InvalidPlatformArchitecture" />
            </InstallConditions>

            <ExitCodes>
                <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
                <ExitCode Value="1602" Result="Fail" String="UserCancelled"/>
                <ExitCode Value="1603" Result="Fail" String="GeneralFailure"/>
                <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
                <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
            </ExitCodes>
        </Command>
    </Commands>

    <!-- Defines a localizable string table for error messages-->
    <Strings>
        <String Name="DisplayName">TestApp</String>
        <String Name="Culture">en</String>
        <String Name="AdminRequired">Administrator permissions are required to install TestApp. Contact your administrator.</String>
        <String Name="InvalidPlatformWinNT">Installation of TestApp requires Windows XP SP2, Windows 2003 SP1, Windows Vista, or later. Contact your application vendor.</String>
        <String Name="InvalidPlatformArchitecture">This version of TestApp is not supported on an IA-64 operating system. Contact your application vendor.</String>
        <String Name="UserCancelled">The user has cancelled the installation. TestApp has not been installed.</String>
        <String Name="GeneralFailure">A failure occurred attempting to install TestApp.</String>
    </Strings>
</Package>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem...

The clickOnce installer is a 32-bit process, the OS is 64-bit consequently the registry check keys get automatically redirected to WOW6432Node.

Comment: This happens because setup.exe generated by Visual Studio is x86... Did you found a way to tell the registry check to verify the x64 keys instead of x86?